# Как узнать уровень вложенности?

Tags: xml, php

Как при помощи DOMxml либо любой другой библиотеки узнать уровень вложенности `<node>`? Никогда не приходилось задаваться подобным вопросом, а сейчас просто приперло к стенке. 
Буду благодарен за помощь, спасибо.

```
<main>
    <fuel> Топливо
        <filings> Заправки
            <node>
                <node>
                    <node>
                        <node>
                        </node>
                    </node>
                </node>
            </node>
        </filings>
        <thefts> Сливы
            <node> 
                <node>
                    <node>
                        Узнать уровень вложенности данного элемента
                    </node>
                </node>
            </node>
        </thefts>
    </fuel>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну так и в чём сложность? Если у вас есть DOM-дерево документа и ссылка на ноду, глубину которой надо выяснить, так идите вверху по ссылкам parentNode, пока не дойдёте до корня и считайте. Вот и узнаете глубину.

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так (псевдокод):

```
XMLNode n = theNode; // инициализировали вашим узлом
int depth = 0;
while(n) {
    n = n.parent;
    ++depth;
}
```

Если же надо искать глубину не относительно корня, а относительно какого-то еще узла, например thefts, делаем `while(n != thefts)`.

Answer (score 0):

Просто гнать цикл пока есть родители и все.